# How to pass a value from one card-div to another

Tags: javascript, angular

I've created a component with three parallel div cards in bootstrap.

The first card has a list of products, and when I click on a product, the second card should show it's details on the same page, but this isn't occurring and I'm not sure why.

I've tried calling a method when the list is clicked, which worked when it was one list.

I used ngFor for the dynamic list so I'm unable to see output on that card.

```
`
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            <button class="btn-primary" routerLink="/template/{{id}}"> <i class="material-icons"> add_circle</i></button>

        </div>

        <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let temp of templates"> 
            <a routerLink=" " class="list-group-item" (click)="temp(1)">{{temp.name}}</a>         
        </ul>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 pd-2" >
    <div class="card">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" routerLink="/template/{{id}}"><i class="material-icons">
            create
            </i></button>
        <div class="template-output">
            {{tempList}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="card">
        <form >
          <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Send Form</mat-label>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the item's index in the on click function:

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let temp of templates; let i = index"> 
   <a class="list-group-item" (click)="temp(i)">{{temp.name}}</a>         
</ul>
```

Then, in your controller you can set the current item using the index.

```
currentTemp:Template;

temp(index:number) {
   this.currentTemp = this.templates[index];
}
```

Finally, in your second card, you can display the info of your selected item:

```
<div class="card">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" routerLink="/template/{{currentTemp.id}}">
    <i class="material-icons">create</i>
  </button>
  <div>{{currentTemp.name}}</div>
</div>
```